# Visual Studio - Qt VS Tools won't compile anything

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

It doesn't matter if I choose Qt widget or whatever project type I can, I get this error when I run my solution:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB4019 The imported project "D:\Teme Proiecte\Programare\QtWidgetsApplication3\QtWidgetsApplication3\QtMsBuild\Qt.props" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "D:\Teme Proiecte\Programare\QtWidgetsApplication3\QtWidgetsApplication3\QtMsBuild\Qt.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.   D:\Teme Proiecte\Programare\QtWidgetsApplication3\QtWidgetsApplication3\QtWidgetsApplication3.vcxproj   D:\Teme Proiecte\Programare\QtWidgetsApplication3\QtWidgetsApplication3\QtWidgetsApplication3.vcxproj   54
```

Maybe it has something to do with my laptop registers?

I reinstalled Qt extension and Qt and I got again this error. Things were fine before I changed something in my laptop to be able to change my user name.

Comment: Did you do what the error message asks? `Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "D:\Teme Proiecte\Programare\QtWidgetsApplication3\QtWidgetsApplication3\QtMsBuild\Qt.props" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.` Does that path seem plausible to you? Does the file exist on disk?

Comment: Given what you said about your user name this is possibly a permissions issue. So maybe you could describe exactly what is was that you did. Basically the more information you can give the more likely you are to get a helpful answer.

Comment: That file doesn't exists, i changed my username back and every new qt project i create will work again

Comment: Usually `Qt.props` exists in` %LOCALAPPDATA%` ,  `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\QtMsBuild` in my case. I need to set environment variable `set QtMsBuild=%LOCALAPPDATA%\QtMsBuild` to run the project.

Comment: You may want to avoid spaces in your path. Your problem could be caused by having: `D:\Teme Proiecte` instead of `D:\TemeProiecte` or `D:\Teme_Proiecte` At work I am a Qt developer on Visual Studio Community since 2008 but I don't use the addon. Instead I use CMake.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue in my system and QT integration in Visual Studio 2019/2022.

Problem was from incorrect QtMsBuild path, that i probably set myself when installed QT some months ago and thought this is a temp folder for QT build files.

Solution is in `Edit the system environment variables` find a `QtMsBuild` entry and delete it.
After that on a first run of a QT VS Tools options it will automatically set to  `%LOCALAPPDATA%\QtMsBuild`.